# catkin_generate_changelog issue with a repo that consolidated multiple repos

Tags: ros, catkin, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On a repository that consolidated packages from multiple repos, I can't seem to update the existing `CHANGELOG.rst`. What's the issue and is there a way to proceed?

```
$ cd moveit
$ catkin_generate_changelog
Found packages: moveit, moveit_commander, moveit_controller_manager_example, moveit_core, moveit_fake_controller_manager, moveit_ikfast, moveit_planners, moveit_planners_ompl, moveit_plugins, moveit_ros, moveit_ros_benchmarks, moveit_ros_benchmarks_gui, moveit_ros_control_interface, moveit_ros_manipulation, moveit_ros_move_group, moveit_ros_perception, moveit_ros_planning, moveit_ros_planning_interface, moveit_ros_robot_interaction, moveit_ros_visualization, moveit_ros_warehouse, moveit_setup_assistant, moveit_simple_controller_manager
Querying commit information since latest tag...
ERROR: Could not fetch latest tag:
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
```

With `--all` option, I can create a new CHANGELOG.rst file for a package that misses it (`moveit`, metapkg).

```
$ catkin_generate_changelog --all
Found packages: moveit, moveit_commander, moveit_controller_manager_example, moveit_core, moveit_fake_controller_manager, moveit_ikfast, moveit_planners, moveit_planners_ompl, moveit_plugins, moveit_ros, moveit_ros_benchmarks, moveit_ros_benchmarks_gui, moveit_ros_control_interface, moveit_ros_manipulation, moveit_ros_move_group, moveit_ros_perception, moveit_ros_planning, moveit_ros_planning_interface, moveit_ros_robot_interaction, moveit_ros_visualization, moveit_ros_warehouse, moveit_setup_assistant, moveit_simple_controller_manager
The following packages already have a changelog file and will be ignored: moveit_commander, moveit_controller_manager_example, moveit_core, moveit_fake_controller_manager, moveit_ikfast, moveit_planners, moveit_planners_ompl, moveit_plugins, moveit_ros, moveit_ros_benchmarks, moveit_ros_benchmarks_gui, moveit_ros_control_interface, moveit_ros_manipulation, moveit_ros_move_group, moveit_ros_perception, moveit_ros_planning, moveit_ros_planning_interface, moveit_ros_robot_interaction, moveit_ros_visualization, moveit_ros_warehouse, moveit_setup_assistant, moveit_simple_controller_manager
Querying all tags and commit information...
Generating changelog files with all versions...
- creating 'moveit/CHANGELOG.rst'
Done.
Please review the extracted commit messages and consolidate the changelog entries before committing the files!

$ tree -L 1
.
├── moveit
├── moveit_commander
├── moveit_core
├── moveit_experimental
├── moveit_ikfast
├── moveit_planners
├── moveit_plugins
├── moveit_ros
├── moveit.rosinstall
├── moveit_setup_assistant
└── README.md
```

There's no git `tag` yet in the repo.

Repo and branch URL: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/tree/jade-devel
Thank you.

---

UPDATE) I just [selected the answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/242004/catkin_generate_changelog-issue-with-a-repo-that-consolidated-multiple-repos/?answer=242005#post-id-242005).

Also tried but not working for my particular case where the new repo is simply an aggregation of multiple packages and maintains the folder structure of original repos, I went down into each "original" folder and ran `catkin_generate_changelog`. But because the original `.git` files are removed in order for the new repo to work as a single git repo, the command fails.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242004/catkin_generate_changelog-issue-with-a-repo-that-consolidated-multiple-repos/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2016-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think this tool will work anymore because the tags from the old repositories were not (and probably could not) be migrated. You'll probably have to create the missing changelog files and manually craft the changelog entries for the first version that has a tag in the merged repository. After that it might "just work" again.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar problem recently. The main problem was the disjoint release version numbers.

I finally ended up creating essentially empty `CHANGELOG.rst` files in the newly-imported packages, then using `catkin_generate_changelog` to fill them in, and editing the results.

That would not work very well for a package with a lot of previous history.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-08-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1